# Что было бы если компилятор не следовал правилам PECS?

Tags: java, generics, wildcards

Предположим, что компилятор пропустит вот такой код

```
public List<T> filterSportsmen(Predicate<? extends T> predicate) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (T sportsman : sportsmen) {
        if (predicate.test(sportsman)) {
            result.add(sportsman);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

    public void addSportsman(Supplier<? super T> supplier){
    sportsmen.add(supplier.get());
}
```

Какие из этого проблемы последуют? И почему компилятор следует правилу PECS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если бы компилятор это позволил, то возникли бы проблемы. Вот для примера с `consumer`-ом, допустим имеем такую иерархию:

```
  class Athlet {
     public getName() { return ... }
  }

  class Thrower extends Athlet {
  }

  class Runner extends Athlet {
    int speed;
    public int getSpeed() { return speed; }
  }
```

И предикат:

```
  class IsQuickEnough implements Predicate<Runner> {
    @Override
    public boolean test(Runner t) {
      return t.getSpeed() > 100;
    }
  }
```

Тогда возникли бы проблемы с таким кодом (тут я предполагаю, что `filterSportsmen` определена в классе `Sportsmen`):

```
Sportsmen<Athlet> athlets = new Sportsmen<>();
athlets.add(new Thrower());

athlets.filterSportsmen(new IsQuickEnough());
```

Проблема возникла бы потому, что `IsQuickEnought` знает точный тип своего аргумента (`Runner`) и использует специфические для этого типа функции и поля. А метод `filterSportsmen` (если бы приведенный в вопросе код был допустимым) передает в `Predicate.test` объекты про которые известно лишь то, что они наследуют от `T`( в этом случае `Athlet`) а значит туда можно передать объект любого типа унаследованный от `Athlet`, не обязательно `Runner`. Соответсвенно компилятор это запрещает.

Аналогично с `producer`-ом. Он может сгенерировать объект родительского класса, скажем `Object`, т.к. тип `Supplier<? super T>` позволяет передать туда `Supplier<Object>`. А понятно, что `Object` вставлять в `sportsment` нельзя. Если представить, что можно, то тогда возникает проблема в коде, который попробует вызвать `getName` у такого объекта.